# Matlab GUI Table

Tags: matlab

right now I'm following an Matlab tutorial http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/brpat2g.html .
The Problem is my Matlab Version r2006a the GUIDE GUI Builder doesn't have an table tool. Does any one know how to figure out in which version it was introduced?

so long
eactor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MathWorks have just put the documentation of past releases till R13sp2 online. You can check them [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) in order to find where `uitable` first appears.

`uitable` was useable before it appeared in the documentation, though it is only since R2008a that it is officially supported.

Comment: It should be noted that you need to create a MathWorks account and associate it with a [license number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/license.html) to access the archived documentation.